# Fan speeds stay the same

Tags: speed, fan, rpm

My nvidia card always is at 28% fan speed. Why does this never change as the temperature goes up? Wouldn't that make it cooler, and thus, better? Is using software to increase that speed perfectly fine to use? (what would you even use?)

Comment: What software are you using to read the current fan speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use msi-afterburner for that.  I wouldn't trust your pc to do it itself unless it has software controlling it.  It's possible some video cards monitor it themselves but that doesn't sound like it's the case for you.

http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm

Comment: Is it safe to use? Won't damage anything?

Comment: I only tweak the fan speed stuff, not the overclock stuff.  Lots of people do overclock but don't do it without knowing what you're doing.  By default msi afterburner doesn't let you overclock without turning on the capability though so you'll be ok.

Comment: How much higher do you make it? Like stated, mine sits at 28% without modification.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your bios are up-to-date, either your temp. doesn't increase that high or a messed configuration.

- Check your Bios and disable Fan Always on. You can use [RealTempGT](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/Real_Temp/) to monitor your temp. while video/gaming.
- Or "possibly" control your fan with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php).
- For testing this benchmark program helps 3DMark at 3DMark.com.

Comment: Temp usually only gets to about 60% of the max temp. Is that good for cpu/gpu's?

Comment: That's good 60%. Mine is 50% iddle and when gaming fans kick high at 80%.